# I have a leaky shower. Builder thinks a total renovation to bathroom is needed to waterproof whole bathroom

Tags: bathroom, leak, waterproofing

So the builder I got in thinks I should remove shower, vanity and toilet. Basically a renovation of the whole bathroom upstairs to waterproof the bathroom. The leak is obvious that it is from the shower. Is what he's saying excessive?

Comment: How can we possibly answer this? Bring in a second (and third) contractor! Get a second opinion from someone ONSITE.

Comment: Not even a chance without good pictures, but regardless you'll need a second opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an access panel below the shower you can look for yourself and see exactly where its comming from. If it is just the drain pipe seal it can be resealed without tearing the whole place up. Did the contractor open up the ceiling below the shower?  I agree a second opinion is needed.

Comment: Thanks. I got a second and third opinion.  One from a waterproofer who thinks we can rip the tiles off the shower floor and 2 rows off the sides, put new shower in ($2000). The other one is to do what you suggested Dave which is cut up an access hole in the ceiling and see what it is..etc The ceiling has to be fixed regardless so he thinks to start there and then get plumber to do testing etc..(unknown depends on findings). The major bathroom renovation quote was ($11,000)...I know I don't want to do the major renovation if I can help it.